# What determines the process name in ps aux?

Tags: linux, bash, ps

I'm trying to track down this script called `./launch.sh`, that on my machine is currently in an infinite loop in which it calls a Java program, immediately crashes, then sleeps for 3 seconds.

`ps aux` includes:

```
   31337  0.1  0.1  19716  2180 pts/3    S+   15:13   0:00 bash   
root     31621  0.3  0.3  22912  5492 pts/4    Ss+  15:15   0:00 -bash
root     31810  0.0  0.0   5872   604 pts/1    S+   15:16   0:00 sleep 3
root     31811  0.0  0.0  16872  1268 pts/2    R+   15:16   0:00 ps aux
```

As well as many `-bash`.

My launch script was called via `./launch.sh`.  This script does not begin with a shebang.

Linux version is as follows:

```
Linux version 3.2.0-23-virtual (buildd@crested) (gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu4) ) #36-Ubuntu SMP
```

So basically wondering why `launch.sh` doesn't show up in `ps aux`, or if there's a way to find it more easily in the process list.  It took me a while to realize I simply had this running in the foreground somewhere.

Comment: A `#!` is a shebang.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A script invoked as `./launch.sh` will simply show up as *bash* (or whatever your default shell is) in ps's output.

To find out with PID is associated with your script, you can use [lsof](http://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof), which lists the processes that opened the file.

Example output:

```
$ lsof launch.sh 
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
bash    17085 dennis  254r   REG    8,1       28 2500332 launch.sh
$
$ ps up 17085
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
dennis   17085  0.0  0.1  28292  4260 pts/2    S+   11:28   0:00 bash
```